# To make query if Suppliers has status Inactive from his Users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There are Supplier model and User model in my project, every Supplier has a few Users
Supplier model

```
public class SupplierRow
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public bool Subscribed { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int Visits { get; set; }

    public bool AllUsersInactive { get; set; }
}
```

and User model

```
public class UserRow
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }

    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public bool SupplierIsInactive { get; set; }
}
```

in controller for Suppliers I check if all Users for every Supplier don't have status Active

```
    public ActionResult Grid(bool? active)
    {
        var suppliers = Context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking()
            .WhereIf(active != null, e => e.Active == active)
            .Select(e => new SupplierRow
                            {
                                Id = e.Id,
                                FullName = e.FullName,
                                Active = e.Active,
                                Visits = e.Visits,
                            })
                            .ToList();

        var supplierIds = suppliers.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
        var suppliersActivityMap = Context.Users.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(e => supplierIds.Contains(e.SupplierId.Value))
            .Select(e => new 
            {
                Status = e.Status,
                SupplierId = e.SupplierId.Value
            })
            .ToList()
            .GroupBy(u => u.SupplierId)
            .Select(x => new 
                { 
                    SuplierId = x.Key, 
                    AllInactive = x.All(u => u.Status != UserStatus.Active) 
                })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.SuplierId);

        foreach (var supplier in suppliers)
        {
            supplier.AllUsersInactive = suppliersActivityMap.ContainsKey(supplier.Id) 
                ? suppliersActivityMap[supplier.Id].AllInactive
                : true;
        }

        return PartialView("_Grid", suppliers);
    }
```

**UPD** and I have controller for Users

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
    {
        var supplierOfUser = Context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking()
            //.Include(e => e.Supplier)
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);


        ViewData.Add("id", id);
        ViewData.Add("SupplierFullName", supplierOfUser.FullName);
        return View();
    }
```

and I need to add here the checking if Supplier for his Users has status inactive, but I don't know how to make a query.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard coding without real objects, I hope this is correct:

```
public ActionResult Grid(int? status, Pager pager, Guid? supplierId)
{

    var sActive = Context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking()
       .WhereIf(o=> o.Id == supplierId)
       .Select(o=> o.Active).FirstOrDefault();

    var page = Context.Users.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(e => e.SupplierId == supplierId)
        .WhereIf(status != null, e => (e.Status == status))
        .Select(e => new UserRow
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            FullName = e.FullName,
            Email = e.Email,
            Name = e.Name,
            Status = e.Status,
            Role = e.Role,
            SupplierIsInactive = !sActive
        })
        .GetPage(pager, Sorter.Asc<UserRow, string>(e => e.FullName));

    return PartialView("_Grid", page);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, I added in my question wrong part of controller, now I replaced it. How can I add here the checking if Supplier for his Users has status inactive?

Comment: In order to answer to your question we have to know ste structure of the classes Context.Users and Context.Suppliers
I guess you should use the sintax Supplier.Users.Any(o => !o.IsActive)